# Update values does not retrieve from table using selenium python

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath

I am trying to access the data between >*.*< from following code by using Selenium in Python.

```
<tbody>
                        <tr>                
                                <td>
    <div class="answer-votes" title="Asked 8 non-wiki questions with a total score of 164. Gave 84 non-wiki answers with a total score of 337." onclick="window.location.href='/search?q=user:37181+[python]'">337</div>
    <a href="/search?q=user:37181+[python]" class="post-tag" title="">python</a>
    <span class="item-multiplier" title="93 posts in the python tag"><span class="item-multiplier-x">×</span>&nbsp;<span class="item-multiplier-count">93</span></span></td>
                                <td>
    <div class="answer-votes" title=" Gave 4 non-wiki answers with a total score of 22." onclick="window.location.href='/search?q=user:37181+[django-templates]'">22</div>
    <a href="/search?q=user:37181+[django-templates]" class="post-tag" title="">django-templates</a>
    <span class="item-multiplier" title="4 posts in the django-templates tag"><span class="item-multiplier-x">×</span>&nbsp;<span class="item-multiplier-count">4</span></span></td>
                                <td>
    <div class="answer-votes" title=" Gave 1 non-wiki answer with a total score of 12." onclick="window.location.href='/search?q=user:37181+[slug]'">12</div>
    <a href="/search?q=user:37181+[slug]" class="post-tag" title="">slug</a>
    </td>
                                <td>
    <div class="answer-votes" title=" Gave 1 non-wiki answer with a total score of 8." onclick="window.location.href='/search?q=user:37181+[google-app-engine]'">8</div>
    <a href="/search?q=user:37181+[google-app-engine]" class="post-tag" title=""><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/vobok.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">google-app-engine</a>
    </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>                
                                <td>
    <div class="answer-votes" title="Asked 1 non-wiki question with a total score of 89. Gave 56 non-wiki answers with a total score of 235." onclick="window.location.href='/search?q=user:37181+[django]'">235</div>
    <a href="/search?q=user:37181+[django]" class="post-tag" title="">django</a>
    <span class="item-multiplier" title="57 posts in the django tag"><span class="item-multiplier-x">×</span>&nbsp;<span class="item-multiplier-count">57</span></span></td>
                                <td>
    <div class="answer-votes" title="Asked 1 non-wiki question with a total score of 21. Gave 1 non-wiki answer with a total score of 22." onclick="window.location.href='/search?q=user:37181+[clang]'">22</div>
    <a href="/search?q=user:37181+[clang]" class="post-tag" title="">clang</a>
    <span class="item-multiplier" title="2 posts in the clang tag"><span class="item-multiplier-x">×</span>&nbsp;<span class="item-multiplier-count">2</span></span></td>
                                <td>
    <div class="answer-votes" title=" Gave 1 non-wiki answer with a total score of 12." onclick="window.location.href='/search?q=user:37181+[connect]'">12</div>
    <a href="/search?q=user:37181+[connect]" class="post-tag" title="show all posts by this user in 'connect'">connect</a>
    </td>
                                <td>
    <div class="answer-votes" title=" Gave 1 non-wiki answer with a total score of 8." onclick="window.location.href='/search?q=user:37181+[memcached]'">8</div>
    <a href="/search?q=user:37181+[memcached]" class="post-tag" title="">memcached</a>
    </td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
```

However, my program does not show the updated value of `<td>` when the compiler moves to the next `<td>`. Could you please guide me how I can fix this issue? Here is my code:

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/37181/alex-gaynor?tab=tags")
SMRTable = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='user-tags'] //td")



for i in SMRTable:

    print(i.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    print(i.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='answer-votes']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    print(i.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='post-tag']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    print(i.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='item-multiplier-count']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle each `td` in `table` you need to specify dot (context character) in the beginning of each XPath expression, e.g. replace

```
print(i.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='answer-votes']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

with

```
print(i.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='answer-votes']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Otherwise, you will get the same values (values from the first `td` only) on each iteration

Also note that you should not use `get_attribute('innerHTML')` to get text content of node, use `text` property instead:

```
print(i.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='answer-votes']").text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code attempt was near perfect. You need to take care of a couple of additional things:

- While you `find_elements_by_xpath()` for *SMRTable* add the *tagName* which is `table`.
- While printing the *innerHTML* as you are referring to the elements within *SMRTable* you have to set the reference through **`.`** (*dot* operator).
- `//div[@class='answer-votes']` is the immediate child tag, so change it as `./div[@class='answer-votes']`
- `//*[@class='post-tag']` is always within a `<a>` tag so you need to use `.//a[@class='post-tag']`
- Your effective code will be:

  ```
  driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/37181/alex-gaynor?tab=tags")
  SMRTable = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='user-tags']//tr/td")
  for i in SMRTable:
      print(i.find_element_by_xpath("./div[@class='answer-votes']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
      print(i.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='post-tag']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
      print(i.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='item-multiplier-count']").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  337
  python
  93
  22
  django-templates
  4
  ```